# How do I import users from an old database into a new Joomla MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5, sobipro

So I have this old list of usernames and email addresses supplied by a client containing the fields `Business Type` `Name` `Date registered` `Telephone` and `Email`

I have posted an html version of the php file that contains the php code here http://www.localdirectoryltd.co.uk/admini/business-list.html. If you inspect the code you will see the lines of php.

I have recreated the website that uses this list of users using Joomla and SobiPro. I now need to recreate the user accounts on the new site as normal Joomla registered users.

I know how to locate the user table in the new Joomla MySQL database using PHPmyAdmin.

I have no idea where to start or how I would go about moving the usernames, names and email addresses to the new database. Can anyone with MySQL and Joomla experience please help and send me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: Personally I would advise not giving out that URL, as you have just handed out a list of peoples names and email addresses.  Total breach of any privacy right there.  Instead supply sample data.

Comment: Thank you, I have now removed the php file and left an html version so people can see the code when inspecting. The old website (not built by me) has nothing but breaches of privacy all over it. The directoriesand files  were all set to permissions 777 throughout the entire site, so that file has never been confidential. It's contact forms were under constant attack and the site stopped working last month.

Answer (score 1):

There's a component for this. It's called userport and you can find it in the Joomla Extensions Directory: http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=userport.

You'll have to make a csv file or something in the like, but it should be pretty straightforward.